# Why does this bash script launch vlc twice?

Tags: bash, vlc

Here is a script I have for launching vlc with a dynamic playlist

```
#!/bin/bash

find "/path/to/music" -type f -path "*$1*" -print0 | xargs -0 vlc
```

When run with no arguments, vlc launches and the files in the directory tree are played.

**Then I close vlc, and another instance launches.**

If I compare the playlist in each instance to the output of

```
find "/path/to/music" -type f -path "**"
```

It turns out that the first instance gets most of the playlist and the second instance gets the rest. The split is deterministic. Here is an extract of the output of the above command:

```
...
/path/to/music/Liz Carroll/Lost in the Loop/08 - The Crow in the Sun.ogg
/path/to/music/Liz Carroll/Lost in the Loop/02 - The Champaign Jig Goes To Columbia, Pat and Al's.ogg
/path/to/music/Liz Carroll/Lost in the Loop/04 - The Golden Legs, The Flogging Reel.ogg
/path/to/music/Liz Carroll/Lost in the Loop/09 - The Ugly Duckling.ogg
/path/to/music/Liz Carroll/Lost in the Loop/03 - See It There, Con Cassidy's.ogg
/path/to/music/Liz Carroll/Lost in the Loop/13 - The Didda, Fly and Dodger.ogg
/path/to/music/Eliza Carthy/Dreams of Breathing Underwater/08 Little Bigman.mp3
/path/to/music/Eliza Carthy/Dreams of Breathing Underwater/07 Lavenders.mp3
...
```

The split always happens such that the last three files are the first in the playlist of the second instance. There don't appear to be any trick characters in there. Filenames conaining apostrophes appear in the vlc playlist as they should, nothing seems to be missing, and vlc outputs no errors.

Why does the first instance of vlc not get all the files in the output of `find`?

Why is there a second instance which gets the rest?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a maximum number of characters you can pass as command line arguments. That's what `xargs` is for: To split the input into multiple chunks and pass them to separate program invocations if their combined size would be too large.

As `man xargs` says:

> The command line for command is built up until it reaches a system-defined limit (unless the `-n` and `-L` options are used).  The specified
>      command will be invoked as many times as necessary to use up the list
>      of input items.  In general, there will be many fewer invocations of
>      command than there were items in the input.

In your case, thousands of input items were processed in two `vlc` invocations.

Comment: You could shorten the paths (and maybe fit them all into one invocation) by having the script do `cd "/path/to/music" || { echo "Error cd'ing" >&2; exit 1; }`, then `find . -type f ...`